# Why didn't Rem die after killing Kaneboshi?

Tags: death-note

In the Death Note anime, Rem kills [Ginzo Kaneboshi](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Ginzo_Kaneboshi) in episode 21 to help Misa convince Higuchi that she is the second Kira. But why didn't Rem die after this? If she died after killing Watari/L, but why not after killing Kaneboshi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because a Shinigami can die only if they try to **extend** or **prolong** the life of a human. In this case, Misa was not in any danger, and killing Ginzo would in no way extend Misa's life directly.

This excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinigami_%28Death_Note%29#Overview) explains that Shinigami can die only by saving a human life (emphasis mine):

> Like humans, Shinigami also can die, of sorts by extending the life of a human they care about (by saving them from certain death): the
>   **purpose of a Shinigami is to end life, not give it, and hence saving a human is contrary to their nature**. Shinigami who die in this manner are reduced to dust. Their Death Note is left behind. The other way that a Shinigami can die is that they stop writing names in their Death Note- since Shinigami take human lifespans for their own when they write a name in their Death Note, if they stop they will eventually die when their lifespan runs out.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: But Rem can see her lifespan. He should have seen her life wasn't in danger, right? By showing himsef and tell everything he must have altered something in time...